# mongo query in python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a command line argument user_id as --uid.

I want to access the record of that particular user_id from another collection "student_details" in python.

As I am new to mongoDB, I would like to get the answer for my particular query

```
users={
_id :Object(###),
name:"",
standard:""
..
..
..
}


student_details={
_id:Object(###),
user_id:"", -----> referenced
..
}
```

I tried doing this,

```
collection = db['student_details']
query = "%s" % option.uidfile
results = collection.find({"user_id":query})

print results
```

ouput:

```
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x95c910c>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe provide some code, your table structure, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at the tutorial here
http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.0/tutorial.html
But if you had collection "student_details" opened in python you would query:

```
collection.find({"userID" : user_id})
```

Comment: I tried doing this,

collection = db['student_details']
query = "%s" % option.uidfile
results = collection.find({"user_id":query})

for i in results:
  print i